# How can I embed video in my Sencha Touch app?

Tags: ipad, video, html, html5-video, sencha-touch

I'm working on a Sencha Touch ipad app which pulls content from a JSON feed. The JSON contains some images, plus some video URLs from Youtube and Vimeo.

Where do I start trying to play embedded video in the app?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A few weeks on from my original question, I have a few tips to share on this topic.

We've built an app quite similar to the Sencha Touch demo app [Touchstyle](http://touchstyle.mobi/). One difference was we wanted to display videos as well as images referenced in our JSON feed.

Our JSON looks something like this for a single item of media, which could be of type `image` or `video`:

```
"Media": [{  
    "id":"28542",  
    "title":"mirrortrackmovie",  
    "type":"video",  
    "thumb":"http:\/\/i.ytimg.com\/vi\/X-z3_-7pwZ0\/default.jpg",  
    "video_host":"youtube",  
    "video_id":"X-z3_-7pwZ0",  
    "video":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/v\/X-z3_-7pwZ0"  
}]
```

In order to embed Youtube and Vimeo videos in Sencha Touch, you have to use the iframe embed code that both sites provide. The following XTemplate inserts the correct `video_id` into the relevant embed code, depending on where the video is hosted.

```
tpl: new Ext.XTemplate(  
    '{[this.renderMedia(values)]}',  
    {
        renderMedia: function(media) {  
            if (media.video) {                              
                if (media.video_host == 'vimeo') {  
                    return '<div class="video vimeo"><iframe class="vimeo-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/'+media.video_id+'?byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=ffffff" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>';  
                } else {  
                    return '<div class="video youtube"><iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'+media.video_id+'" frameborder="0"></iframe></div>';}  
                }    
            }  
        }  
    }  
)
```

By and large this method has worked fine, although we did experience some problems to do with loading video in a buffered carousel (a topic for another question).

Comment: Could you show example on how you use that XTemplate with Panel?

Answer (score 0):

You can start by looking into the Sencha Touch Kitchensink : Media > Video Example

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/kitchensink/

Comment: Thanks herkulano - that was my starting point, but it only caters for locally-hosted video, not video embedded from a 3rd-party site.